# Error al cargar ruta en Laravel Homestead y MySQL

Tags: mysql, laravel

Cuando cargo el siguiente código en un proyecto de laravel

```
Route::get("/leer",function(){
$articulos=\App\Articulo::all();
    foreach($articulos as $articulo){
        echo $articulo->Nombre_Articulo;
    }
});
```

me sale este error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y cuando lo actualizo me sale esto en la pantalla

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

estoy trabajando con laravel homestead,vagrant y gitbash